# How do I make a cd command take effect outside of the bash script subshell?

Tags: bash, scripting, cd-command

I made this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
  echo "only use one argument"
  exit 1
fi

mkdir $1
sleep 0.5
cd $1

exit 0
```

I wanted to make a script that I would later put into /usr/bin, such that whenever I write `crdir asd` it creates the directory and automatically changes my current directory to the new directory.

This way doesn't work, because the schell script is apparently a subshell, and the cd command will not take effect outside of the subshell, so how would I do this?

I read online that I should "source" it, run it with a dot in front, like `. ./crdir asd`, but first of all, when I tried this, ssh got disconnected from the machine, and secondly, this wouldn't work the way I wanted it to work, as a command.

Any tips?

EDIT: I also tried `mkdir aaa; cd !#` but it didn't work, it took `!#` as the argument from the previous command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a function instead:

```
crdir() {
  if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -P -- "$1"
  else
    echo >&2 "Usage: crdir <directory-path>"
    return 1
  fi
}
```

Which you can put in your `~/.bashrc`.

Your `. crdir` approach would also work (in `bash` and other shells whose `.` can take arguments), but you'd need to remove that `exit 0` which causes the shell to exit. Also note that when not in POSIX mode, `bash` looks for the file to source in the current directory if it can't be found in `$PATH`, which makes it a bit dangerous (at the same level as adding `.` or an empty entry at the end of `$PATH`).

Also if `. crdir` is called without arguments, then the script will inherit the positional parameter of the shell. For instance, `set foo; . crdir` would not return an error and would create the `foo` directory.

A few other notes on your script:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```

Note that the she-bang is ignored (is just seen as a comment) when the file is sourced.

> ```
> if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
>   echo "only use one argument"
> ```

It's preferable to output error messages on stderr (`echo >&2 text`).

> ```
>   exit 1
> fi
>
> mkdir $1
> ```

Leaving parameter expansions unquoted has a special meaning in `bash`, you should almost never do that.

Also, if `$1` starts with a `-`, it will be treated as an option by `mkdir`. You'd need to use the `--` end-of-option marker to tell `mkdir` the content of `$1` is not an option even if it starts with `-`.

You're also not checking if the `mkdir` command succeeded.

You may also want to use the `-p` option which tells `mkdir` to create all the directory components and also causes `mkdir` not to return failure if the directory already existed. So:

```
 mkdir -p -- "$1" &&
```

> ```
> sleep 0.5
> ```

No need to sleep. You can be sure that the directory has been created when `mkdir` returns successfully.

> ```
> cd $1
> ```

Again, you've got the quoting and `-` issues. Also, in `bash` you need the `-P` option for `cd` to interpret paths the same way as other utilities like `mkdir`. So:

```
 cd -P -- "$1"
```

(ignoring for now a path called `-` or `$CDPATH` which I'd hope you don't use or use only with sane values).

> ```
> exit 0
> ```

Again, you're not checking the exit status of `cd` and returning with a *success* exit status, even if `mkdir` or `cd` failed. When a script is sourced, it's interpreted by the sourcing shell, so that `exit` would cause it to exit.

Here, I'd rewrite the script as:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
  mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -P -- "$1"
else
  ! echo >&2 "Usage: crdir  <directory-path>"
fi
```

Comment: What are the double dashes in `mkdir -p -- "$1"`? Also the lack of exit status checks is because I just wanted to see how to make it work first.

Comment: @iamAguest, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about a function:

```
crdir() { mkdir $1; cd $1; }
```